# Separate Y and UV of a video frame

Tags: three.js, glsl, yuv

I have an incoming video texture in Yuv format, I need to separate each of this video frame into Y plane and UV plane separately. I dont know whether it is possible with threejs or should I use a shader. How could I do this either with threejs or glsl?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you probably should implement some kind of shader for this as it is a very parallelizable operation. That said, [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) is just an image channel format, much like RGB, except with the following relationship:

- Y = avg(R,G,B)
- U = R
- V = B

One of the interesting things (and a likely explanation about why separation of Y and UV is your requirement) is that with just Y, you have a black-and-white image. With UV, its possible to determine not only G, but also the color channel gradient fairly easily for image processing pipelines.

Sometimes, there's an extra bit of encoding, but it usually boils down to normalizing.  Your video stream likely has a more specific encoding that includes some compression as well. Still, separation of the channels should be easy:

1. [1 0 0] * [Y U V]^T = Y
2. [[0 1 0],[0 0 1]] * [Y U V]^T = [U V]^T

Shaders (really GPU processing) works wonders with linear algebra, and since the separation can be expressed as linear transforms, I'd go that route.

Comment: how can i access these y and uv values of a texture inside a shader? @jhill515

Comment: It depends on the specific encoding protocol used. Some simple ones use a 24-bit pixel encoding with the first byte as Y, etc. Others may encode them as a three floats. Most shader libraries have utilities to handle those encodings, but you need to specify it. So once as you know, use the matrix equations above in the shader, and you're good to go! :-)

Comment: could u suggest me some shader libraries?

Comment: Typically requests & answers to that question get flagged and pulled by moderators (breaks rules about non-advertisement). That said, you've already tagged GLSL (which is how I came upon this question), so why not that one?

Comment: what I'm asking was, in case of rgb format I can access r or g or b by variable.r or variable.b etc
Similarly How can I access Y,U,V?